# bootstrap pull-right nav-bar with full line and visible

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need edit and repair my nav-bar, to show complete line, in normal mode work without problems, the problem start when i put 'pull-right' attribute.
my actual code is : http://www.bootply.com/JlG7rS8VBA

I need to be visibile like in this image : https://snag.gy/8Xli4z.jpg
in this moment the line is not visible, how i can do this ? where is my mistake ?